# SQL Query fails to update

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-update

I am trying to update a row on an SQL SERVER 2005.  When I run the SQL, I receive a message indicating that the Execution was successful and 1 row was affected.  However, when I do a select against this row I supposedly updated, the value remains unchanged.  What's going on with this SQL server when a successful query does absolutely nothing.

The query is:

```
UPDATE [database1].[dbo].[table1] 
   SET [order] = 215 
WHERE [email] = 'email@email.com'
```

Comment: Post the SQL code so we can take a look at it. Chances are if something isn't working the way you expected, the problem lies in the code.

Comment: Can you show the update and your select verification?  Also, are you using "begin tran[saction]" anywhere?

Comment: This is the SQL update that I am using.  I also updated the table using a gui interface that writes the SQL for me and that doesn't work either.  This seems to be a SQL Server permission issue or something along those lines, but it is definitely not an SQL  problem

UPDATE [database1].[dbo].[table1]
   SET [order] = 215
 WHERE [email] = 'email@email.com'

Comment: There is no begin transaction being used.  This code worked on another SQL 2005 Server with no problem.  I set up another SQL server on another machine and created the Databases from a backup file that came from the previous SQL Server 2005

The SELECT statment is SELECT * FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1] WHERE [email] = 'email@email.com'

Comment: I added the order column recently.  I can update everything else in the table with the exception of this column.

Comment: check for a trigger on [database1].[dbo].[table1], possibly it is doing something you are not aware of.

Comment: what happens if you update [order] and another columnin the same UPDATE?

Comment: If I update additional columns in the same update statment, all other columns update except the order column

Comment: did you check for a trigger?  also make sure that [order] is not a computed column

Comment: Thanks KM

I checked the triggers and you were right.  There was a trigger that I had to disable to get the sql to work.

Answer (score 1):

check for a trigger on [database1].[dbo].[table1], possibly it is doing something you are not aware of.

**EDIT**

without seeing the trigger code, you probably just need to add support for [order] into the trigger, since it is a new column (based on your comment).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KM I checked the triggers and you were right. There was a trigger that I had to disable to get the sql to work.

Comment: OK, so it works now - but that trigger probably was there for a good reason. What did it do? Why did it prevent your update?